# Request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

```
UIImage *img=[[UIImage alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,145,20)];
img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dollor.png"];
```

I get the error "Request for member image in something not a structure or  union" for the above code could any one help.

Also i get the same eror for the code

```
img.tag=1;
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage *img=[[UIImage alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,145,20)];
```

should be

```
UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,145,20)];
```

Replace this and everything will be fine...

Comment: Just click the green tick mark next to the answer to highlight it

Comment: UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,145,20)];
 img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dollor.png"];

 [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
 [img release];                                               Is this code right??